# How to construct a Free Leib algebras with example

Tags: lie-algebras

According to the [Examples of Free Lie Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020200/examples-of-free-lie-algebra) we have a useful example for free Lie algebra. Now I want to construct an example for free Leibniz algebra. I faced an example for free Leibniz algebra as follows, but I need your guidance to build free Leibniz algebra on $X=\{x_{1} , x_{2}\}$.

Example: Let we have $\{a,b \}$ such that $[b,a]=a$ and $[b,b]=a$, then it is satisfying Leibniz identity such that  it is a left Leibniz algebra.

Comment: Why not taking the free algebra generated by $x_1,x_2$ quotiented by the Jacobi relation ?

Comment: The construction of a free Leibniz algebra is given [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Leibniz_algebra).

Comment: @N.H. you're right that proving the existence is trivial, but maybe the question is rather to compute a basis. The word "construct" is somewhat vague here.

Comment: @YCor : This make indeed more sense as a question.