# Basis of free Lie-algebra through Lazard-elimination

Tags: lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

How can we construct a basis for free Lie-algebra of rank $2$ generated by two elements $a$, $b$ through Lazard-elimination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Lazard-Shirshov elimination see the well-known paper [Subalgebras of free Lie algebras](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=5381&option_lang=eng) by A. I. Shirshov. A survey on this topic including the various constructions of (linear) bases for free Lie algebras on $m\ge 2$ generators is given by Bokut:

[Gröbner-Shirshov Bases for Lie Algebras: after A. I. Shirshov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.1254.pdf)

See also [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lazard_set) for further references. Hall bases coincide with Lazard-bases. More examples are given in Ralph Stöhr's paper:

[Bases, Filtrations and module decompositions of free Lie algebras](http://eprints.ma.man.ac.uk/703/01/Decom_submit.pdf).

For $2$ generators see [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020200/examples-of-free-lie-algebra).