# A confusion about a linear basis of Lie subalgebra of Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

I have already tried to understand this good explanation: [Basis of free Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475613/basis-of-free-lie-algebra-through-lazard-elimination)

But still I have a confusion in the following case: Let $L(a,b)$ be a free Lie algebra  of rank 2. How is it possible to say that the elements $a, [b,a], [b,[b,a]], [b,b,[b,a]]], ...$ are a basis for a free Lie subalgebra of $L(a,b)$? Because if we do the following calculation between two elements of this basis and use Jacobi Identity we have

> [a,[b,a]]=-[a,[a,b]]-[b,[a,a]]= -[a,[a,b]]

So, the bracket of two elements of the basis can not be written as the bases element! Can we identify that Lie subalgebra with the above-mentioned basis?

Comment: If we assume that b>a then [b,a] is a Lyndon term and ba is Lyndon word. But unfortunately I can not understand how it can be a  basis