# Free Lie algebra over the set $X=\{x\}$

Tags: lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

> How can I describe more concretely the free lie algebra over the singleton $X=\{x\}$? Is there any intuition on how to visualize the free Lie algebra when $X$ is more arbitrary?

By the definition I just know that the free Lie algebra over X is a Lie algebra $L(X)$ generated by $X$ which satisfies the universal property: for every map $\phi:X\rightarrow M, M$ Lie algebra, there exists a unique morphism of Lie algebras $\tilde \phi: L(X) \rightarrow M$ extending $\phi$.

This definition does not give me any intuition on how to describe $L(X)$ concretly . So i've tried to get some intuition via its construction. Well, $L(X)$ is just the subalgebra of the tensor algebra of $V=$ (vector space having $X$ as a basis) generated by $V$. But again for me it is not clear, especially when $X$ is a huge set.

I also have tried just to think about about  a Lie algebra generated by $X$. Since $X$ is just a singleton, any Lie structure over the vector space $V$ must be abelian. And now? How does the property of being free over $X$ works here?

I really would like to get some intuition about this object. Thank you.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020200/examples-of-free-lie-algebra).

Comment: And now? the line generated by $X$ is a subalgebra, period. No, you don't need free: any Lie algebra generated by a single element is at most 1-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $X=\{x\}$, $L(X)$ is the $1$-dim vector space spanned by $x$ with the structure of an abelian Lie algebra (well, any $1$-dim Lie algebra is abelian anyhow).  It satisfies the universal property because any map $\phi:X\to M$, where $M$ is a Lie algebra, if $\tilde{\phi}:L(X) \to M$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism extending $\phi$, then $\tilde{\phi}$ is completely determined by its value at $x$, which is $\phi(x)$.  So, $\tilde{\phi}$ is unique.

I am not sure what kind of intuitions you are looking for.  But the section about [Lyndon basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Lie_algebra#Lyndon_basis) in the wikipedia page may be useful.