# What are the motivations and examples of P. Hall Family?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory, examples-counterexamples, motivation

I am reading J. P. Serre's Lie Algebras and Lie Groups and here is how a P. Hall Family is defined:

[image]

I failed to understand the motivations of this definition. Could anyone explain it to me? Also, some simple examples of P. Hall Families will also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is important, for example, for the theory of free Lie algebras, e.g., a P. Hall basis. As with all definitions, the motivation comes afterwards, rarely before. A good reference is the book [Free Lie algebras](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/free-lie-algebras-9780198536796?cc=at&lang=en&) by Christophe Reutenauer. However, also the book J.-P. Serre you are reading gives motivating results afterwards. For an example, see

[Examples of Free Lie Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020200/examples-of-free-lie-algebra)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Dort haben Sie meine Frage vor 4 Jahren beantwortet. Danke nochmal!

Comment: Ja, ich habe es auch gesehen :)